# How to reverse a fastq file using biopython or other tools?

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I have single reads fastq from Illumina Hiseq, and I would like to generate the reverse using biopython ( or others). 
I can only find information on how to get the reverse complement using reverse_complement(dna), but I dont know how to get only the reverse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just prints out the reverse of the sequence. If you have a need for the quality information in the fastq file, you need to take the reverse of that also!

```py
from Bio import SeqIO

with open('sample.fastq') as handle:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fastq'):
        sequence = str(record.seq)
        reverse_sequence = sequence[::-1]
        print(reverse_sequence)
```

Comment: You should also reverse the quality scores if you plan to keep the fastq format (since the post referred to reversing the file, rather than just the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

a one-liner use **rev** and **tr** to convert the 2nd line (and rev the 4th) of your input.

```
gunzip -c in.fq.gz | while read L; do echo $L && read L && echo $L | rev  |  tr "ATGCN" "TACGN" && read L && echo $L && read L && echo $L | rev ;done
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me, it begins, but then never stops. I don't really understand all of the components of this onliner, but does anybody know how could that be changed?